# Is Parse js reactive?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I.e. with pubsub that you can use to automatically update models and corresponding views?? or is it just a traditional db where you make requests for data, but client side? How would you implement something like Meteor's reactivity in Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com data calls are very much like a traditional db. You can use some kind of refresh loop to get what you want.

Another option is that Parse supports iOS/Android notifications, so you can push to the devices letting them know they need to refresh.